# Equivalent of _set_new_handler for VirtualAlloc()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a data structure for working on large data sets. It essentially acts as a 'view' into on-disk data, loading data from disk as requested; it will try to keep as much data in memory as possible, so that on next access, it doesn't have to read from disk. When it detects out of memory, it does a 'cleanup sweep' of chunks of data with reference count 0. It uses _set_new_handler() to set a function that calls this cleanup when some code, somewhere, tries to malloc() memory but can't. This way, the data structure can consume as much memory as possible, but still 'backs off' when someone else needs some memory.

Now I have the problem that some memory isn't being allocated using malloc() (or new()). I first started seeing it in calls to CreateDIBSection(), and I think it's because this function uses VirtualAlloc() directly. Thus, when allocation fails, the new handler isn't called, and the VirtualAlloc just fails. (I have other cases too with the same situation, but those I can work around; so the CreateDIBSection() one is my main 'demonstration case' of the issue; but working around using that specific API won't fix my general problem)

So my question is - is there an equivalent of _set_new_handler() for VirtualAlloc(), or another way to be notified when VirtualAlloc() fails, so that I can call my 'cleanup memory' functionality and try the allocation again? Alternatively, is there a way to intercept VirtualAlloc() calls, so that I can check for memory availability on every allocation, and clean up when necessary? Thanks.

Comment: `CreateDIBSection` not call `VirtualAlloc` or allocate any memory in user mode. and not exist notify handler on `VirtualAlloc` ot `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`. only of you set hook on this api yourself

Comment: How does CreateDIBSection then allocate memory when you don't pass an hSection? Are there any other low level memory allocation methods?

Comment: they call `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` from kernel. the memory will be free where you call `DeleteObject` for bitmap

Comment: Is this a 32bit app? How are you running out of virtual memory to alloc? And I presume you are also locking the pages in RAM? On a virtual memory operating system (such as windows), "memory" refers to stuff that has an address allocated to it, but may be in RAM or on disk so you seem to have invented a complicated way to make your app break while achieving absolutely nothing.

Comment: Yes it's 32 bit. I didn't write (all of) it and it's 10+ years old code, I can't just switch to 64 bit - but I could still use some band aid to carry me over until I can port this all. So if you have a way to let the (32 bit) OS deal with data sets that are 20-50 GB using virtual memory, please tell.

Comment: [Address Windowing Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Memory/address-windowing-extensions).

Comment: Pretty much every other instance of this kind of behaviour relies on a fixed size buffer allocated at startup. See Java's -Xmx flag. You might want to try build your app with the Large Address Aware switch to make an extra 2GB of VM address space available (assuming a 64bit OS at least). But then, with 10yo code - who can tell if it will actually be large address aware...

Answer (score 1):

"Memory" should not be taken to mean RAM on a modern Virtual Memory based OS - its simply a reserved address range that may be backed by the page file or some other mapped file view. Memory is paged into and out of RAM on demand by the OS but should really be thought of as a disk rather than RAM allocation.

Care must be taken to ensure this is taken into account when attempting to construct usermode memory "caches" as naive attempts will result in a net performace loss as nothing extra will actually be cached in RAM and there will needless extra pagefile allocation to page in and out.

With that in mind I can suggest:

- Using [MapViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) (and related APIs) to create your file "view". This provides the OS the best hints that the file you are viewing is directly paged from its own bytes into RAM as desired and ensures you don't have a wasteful copy & duplication of bytes from source file into pagefile.
- If you cannot rebuild as a 64 bit app, use the /LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE linker switch on your app to get an extra 2GB of potential VM allocation.
- Decide on some configurable limit to your allocation: See the Java runtimes -Xmx flag for an example of how other applications deal with this.
- You can also use [Address Windowing Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/address-windowing-extensions) to manage access to "large" allocations from 32bit apps.
- Or consider using a 64bit partner app that loads the file, and then use [Shared File Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) to manage a shared window onto the allocations made by the 64bit app.

Pragmatically I think using file mappings to create a view (or views) of the file will be simplest to implement and provide reasonable if not the best performance - even if a view is not mapped in your 32bit process that doesn't mean the 64bit underlying OS can't or won't keep those bytes in RAM in its file IO cache.

Comment: This is not technically an answer to the question as it is phrased.